# Inaccurate detection of "subjective" question?

Tags: discussion

I'm not really proposing anything or even asking a question, I just felt this should be pointed out.

[image]

Seems to me the question is very straight forward and answerable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect this is something to do with how you phrased it as "how do ***you*** do x?" Perhaps a less subjective title would be "How ***to*** delete a plan from Microsoft Planner?"

The question is straightforward and answerable as you have proven. It's just the title could, to a robot or when read out loud with a weird rising inflection on the word "you", *sound* like you are canvassing for opinion rather than a solid answer.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.

Comment: @ScottBeeson ;)

Comment: Sadly, the suggested fix, while it produces an acceptable title, is no longer actually a question.  To make a question without "you", one needs first person "How can I...?" or passive voice "How can a plan be deleted from Microsoft Planner?"  (To be clear, it isn't necessary for a question title to be a question, it's perfectly fine to simply name the task and put a real question in the body.  Toward that end, the "how to" actually is fluff, and the title should just be "Delete plan from Microsoft Planner")

Comment: It is the opposite of Quora; Quora hates “how to”.